# Prestashop 1.7 how to add line break

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I try to add a line break `<br>` to the page content (CMS). To do that I switch to source code, but after clicking ok button, the editor removes `<br>` So I guess there is some kind of validation. How can I turn off this or how to add line break? (maybe there is some other way)

Answer (score 0):

you should use `<p></p>` not `<br>` in the source code

Comment: I knew that but there is also coming other styling with it. like you should add margin:0 and padding:0 in your answer and non breaking space in it because it will be removed.

Comment: you can do it <br> directly in the database

Comment: thanks for the clue. I added in the DB and I thought that after I edit cms page and save again it will disappear but to my surprise it stays. I can even add more in admin panel I just type `<br>` and it auto changes to `<br />` so it works, and don't  know how come.